# Polynomial with geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, geometric-progressions

If the roots of an equation with real coefficients $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0, a\ne0$ form a geometric progression, prove $ac^{3}=db^{3}$

I have no idea how to get started, so if it can a few hints?

Comment: Perhaps name the roots $s$, $rs$, and $r^2s$, and then multiply out the polynomial $a(x-s)(x-rs)(x-r^2s)$ and see what the coefficients $b,c,d$ are in terms of $s$ and $r$.

Comment: You've been around long enough to know not to state a problem, followed by anything along the lines of "I have no clue!?"

Answer (score 2):

Say, $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the roots, then by Vieta we have $$x_2^3= x_1x_2x_3 = -{d\over a}$$ and $$x_2(x_1+x_2+x_3) ={c\over a}$$
and
$$x_1+x_2+x_3 =-{b\over a}$$ So from the alst two equation we get $x_2=-{c\over b}$ so putting this one in first equation we get $$-{b^3\over c^3} = -{d\over a}$$ and thus a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Start here:

$$(k_1 - x) (k_2 k_1 - x) (k_2^2 k_1 - x) = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d = 0$$

Comment: How did you get that, by what logic ?

Comment: Factor, and note that the $x$ in each term was related to another by a geometric progression.